# Filling in plot animation (polar function)

Tags: matlab, octave

[image]

I have a set of videos shown in an assignment. How is this animation created? I am trying to create something similar. Below is my attempt; it is only drawing lines because I believe it is not filling in the correct inputs. Guidance would be much appreciated

```
clear;close all;

th = 0:0.1:pi*2
r = cos(2*th) .* sin(2*th);
x = r .* cos(th);
y = r .* sin(th);
plot(x,y);
hold on

for th = 0:0.1:pi*2
  x0 = [r .* cos(th)];
  y0 = [r .* sin(th)];
  fill(x0,y0,'b');
  pause (0.5);
end
hold off
```

Comment: Are you asking just how to draw the final filled figure or how to do the animation as well?

Comment: I'm asking about the animation. I already did draw the final filled figure, also with Cartesian coordinates

Comment: since you can draw the figure, you could try an approach like that linked at https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/395176-how-to-plot-animation-plots making use of the `drawnow` function in a loop plotting a steadily increasing amount of the plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A similar animation can be drawn by filling from lists. Putting `clf` in the for-loop is optional.

This following code animates the drawing process of a small flower. The flower will look proportionally bigger or smaller by changing the axis.

```
X = 0:0.01:pi*2;
r = cos(2*X).*sin(2*X);

x=r.*(cos(X));
y=r.*(sin(X));

x_1 = []; y_1 = [];

for i=1:629                    %629 is the size of x and of y
    x_1 = [x(i), x_1];
    y_1 = [y(i), y_1];
    
    fill(x_1,y_1,'b'); hold on;
    axis([-2 2 -2 2]); hold on;
    pause(0.01);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to draw the function in polar coordinates with polarplot(th, radius), I could not fill with yellow color and neither animate the graph, I'm sorry.

```
clear;close all;

th = linspace(0, 2*pi, 1000);

r = cos(2 .* th) .* sin(2 .* th);

polarplot(th,r)
```

Comment: The animation can also be drawn in polar coordinates using a similar structure as my answer; for example ```[x_1(i),y_1(i)] = pol2cart(x(i),r(i));```